# Adding checkbox array values into several rows in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm making a promotion tool for WordPress where I'm sending out a newsletter to several recipients. To keep track, the selected recipients will be added to a MySQL database.

Each row in the SQL has `id`, `newsletter_id`, `recipient_id` and `promocode` (random generated).

My checkbox array is called recipients[], and I need to insert one row each recipient in the database. Can I somehow make a dynamic SQL query where I insert all in one query, or do I need a loop or something to accomplish this? This is my code so far with a for each.

```
$checkboxes = isset($_POST['recipients']) ? $_POST['recipients'] : array();
foreach(checkboxes as $recipient) {
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO " .$wpdb->prefix ."send(newsletter_id, recipient_id, promocode) VALUES(" .$newsletter_id .", " .$recipient .", " .$promocode .");");
}
```

Are there any better ways to do this? Any suggestions for a solution would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code? Because the short answer is, yes you can collect all your data and loop through it to insert into a db. But we're not going to write the code for you. We'll guide you to your answer through use of your code.

Comment: yes it is possible, does that answer the question @janlindso ?

Comment: use multiple inserts, or use msyql's extended insert syntax `insert ... values (set#1), (set#2), ..., (set#n)`. The choice is up to you.

Comment: @the_pete Yes, I did it with for each loop, but I thought it would be an easier/better way to do it? If you read it again, it is more than a yes/no question. I'm asking for a suggestion for a solution, not complete code.

Comment: @MarcB Are there any differences in terms of server load?

Comment: more overhead parseing/sending the individual queries, but in the big picture, unless you're doing a few trillion records, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: Actually MarcB's suggestion is faster, and reduces the load.
In a single SQL Query, you can send several values (concatenate those values using a foreach loop) is better than using the SQL Query inside a loop, and executing the query on each iteration.
Use MarcB's solution.

Comment: @Chique So, should I create the SQL query with my for each loop then?

Comment: I've explained in my answer below. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we would prepare the set of values as MarcB mentioned. Then we would execute the SQL Query only once outside the loop. Hence will be the fastest approach and fastest loading time.

Try this out

```
$checkboxes = isset($_POST['recipients']) ? $_POST['recipients'] : array();
$sql = array(); 
foreach($checkboxes as $recipient) {
    $sql[] = "(" .$newsletter_id .", " .$recipient .", " .$promocode .")";
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO " .$wpdb->prefix ."send(newsletter_id, recipient_id, promocode) VALUES ".implode(",", $sql).";");
```